# find a process' time in the current state

Tags: command-line, ps

I'm Looking for a way to show the time a certain process is in it's current state.
At the moment, I'm using the command:

```
ps -A -o uname,pid,state,etime,cmd | grep -e pbs | egrep -v "grep"
```

Which give me output like this:

```
root      1613 S  4-00:16:59 /usr/sbin/pbs_server
root     13508 S  1-18:13:37 /usr/sbin/pbs_sched
root     15344 R    01:09:51 /usr/sbin/pbs_mom
```

This tells me `pbs_mom` is running for approx one hour. However, I need to know for how long it has this running state. Is there a way to get this using only the command-line? (since I'm intending to use it in a script)

Comment: How long it has had the current state or how long it has had a running state over all? The former might not be possible, the latter would be the total of real+sys for that process.

Comment: I'm looking for how long it has had the current state

Comment: I don't think that data is maintained anywhere - you'll have to monitor the process's status yourself.

Comment: Okay, and the other option? Could you make a separated comment with the command-line I need to get the total time of running-state? Perhaps it can be of use anyway (if not for me, then maybe for someone else).

Comment: That's easy - just tack on `bsdtime` to the `ps` fields.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry a misunderstanding on my side. I thought you had a method to show the total time a process had the state "running", not just the total time a process exists on the system.

Comment: `bsdtime` is the total time a process was running - it's the sum of `user`+`sys` times. For example, `gnome-shell` has been existing for 7 days, 6 hours on my system and has been running for less than 7 days (144 hours).

Comment: Maybe a useful suggestion for someone else by @muru: print the `time` output instead of `etime`. `time` is the total time a process was running while `etime` is the total time a process exists (so all states accumulated). However for me, it is not the solution to my question. I am looking for the time the process has it's current state. So in other words: I want to know how much time has past since the last time the process changed it's state.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly it is not possible to tell how long the process has been in the **current** state (or at what time the process state changed last) - the kernel doesn't keep this kind of history.

Imagine the vast amount of overhead (processor-time-wise and memory-wise) to keep the timestamps of every context-switch (several hundred to several thousand per second).